# To prove a statement related to quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory

**Let $p$ be a prime and let $$(a,p)=(b,p)=1$$. If $x^2 \equiv (b\; mod p)$ and $$x^2 \equiv (a \; mod p)$$ are not solvable, then prove that $x^2 \equiv (ab \; mod p)$ is solvable.**

*I know that the statements in the theorem(result) is nothing but definition of quadratic residue*

> I need a short proof as I don't have any idea how to start .

Comment: So $a,b\in\Bbb Z_p$ and you want to show that if neither $a$ nor $b$ is a square in $\Bbb Z_p$ then $ab$ is a square. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think this follows from the fact that the [Legendre symbol is multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol), but we have to prove it.

Comment: I know how to prove it now, using the [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

$x^2\equiv a\bmod p$ means $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and similarly, $x^2\equiv b\bmod p$ means $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. So then, in terms of Legendre symbols, we have

$$\Big(\frac{a}{p}\Big)= \Big(\frac{b}{p}\Big)=-1.$$

We need to show $ab$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

We have $$\Big(\frac{ab}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{a}{p}\Big)\Big(\frac{b}{p}\Big)=-1\cdot -1=1,$$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start from scratch, i.e. not using Legendre symbols. All you need to know is that the multiplicative group ${\mathbf F_p}^*$ is cyclic (in general, a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic), so the quotient ${\mathbf F_p}^*/(squares)$ is cyclic of order $2$, hence isomorphic to the group {${\pm 1}$} (this contains the definition of the Legendre symbol !). In the latter group, we have $(-1)(-1)=1$, and a simple translation gives what you want.